# how to get text file in listview containing in Assets folder android studio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, assets

How to show assets folder file names into recycler view in Android Studio?

Files in my Assets folder are Apple.txt, Banana.json, cat.xml, Dog.xml, Elephant.java, Fox.json, Got.gradle etc
i want only name with it's type in list like Apple.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the application's raw asset files by calling APIs provided by `AssetManager`.

```java
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("");  // "" means asset root folder
```

After you get the String array that contains all the assets at the root folder, you can pass the array to your `RecyclerView.Adapter` and bind it to your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        String[] files = new String[0];  // "" means asset root folder
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("activity");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new cvRecyclerAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(files));
         chipsText.setAdapter(adapter);
```